# Merge pandas dataframes based on timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, join

have two dataframe like this (Example)

df1

```
                   Data  Value
0   2020-01-31 10:30:00      3
1   2020-01-31 11:30:00      4
2   2020-01-31 12:30:00     19
3   2020-01-31 13:30:00     22
4   2020-01-31 14:30:00      4
5   2020-01-31 15:30:00      5
6   2020-01-31 15:30:00      6
7   2020-01-31 16:30:00      7
8   2020-01-31 17:30:00      9
9   2020-01-31 18:30:00      7
10  2020-01-31 19:30:00      8
```

df2

```
                DSTART                 DEnd Condition
0  2020-01-31 11:30:00  2020-01-31 12:30:00       BAD
1  2020-01-31 15:30:00  2020-01-31 16:30:00     ERROR
```

Then, I want to join df1 and df2, but I don't know how to do this, because in the second df I just have the start and end time. How can I put the condition on the first df based on the data of the second df?

this is what I want

```
                   Data  Value Condition
0   2020-01-31 10:30:00      3        OK
1   2020-01-31 11:30:00      4       BAD
2   2020-01-31 12:30:00     19       BAD
3   2020-01-31 13:30:00     22       BAD
4   2020-01-31 14:30:00      4        OK
5   2020-01-31 15:30:00      5     ERROR
6   2020-01-31 15:30:00      6     ERROR
7   2020-01-31 16:30:00      7        OK
8   2020-01-31 17:30:00      9        OK
9   2020-01-31 18:30:00      7        OK
10  2020-01-31 19:30:00      8        OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.merge_asof`:

```
# make sure that `Data`, `DSTART`, `DEnd` are datetime type
# use `pd.to_datetime` if needed
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2, left_on='Data', right_on='DSTART')

df1['Condition'] = tmp['Condition'].where(tmp['Data'] <= tmp['DEnd'], 'OK')
```

Output:

```
                  Data  Value Condition
0  2020-01-31 10:30:00      3        OK
1  2020-01-31 11:30:00      4       BAD
2  2020-01-31 12:30:00     19       BAD
3  2020-01-31 13:30:00     22        OK
4  2020-01-31 14:30:00      4        OK
5  2020-01-31 15:30:00      5     ERROR
6  2020-01-31 15:30:00      6     ERROR
7  2020-01-31 16:30:00      7     ERROR
8  2020-01-31 17:30:00      9        OK
9  2020-01-31 18:30:00      7        OK
10 2020-01-31 19:30:00      8        OK
```

Comment: @Quanq I try like this
`
tmp = pd.merge_asof(_dadosPIMS,_dadosMan, left_on='Data', right_on='Inicio Real')

_dadosPIMS['Falha'] = tmp['Falha'].where(tmp['Data'] <= tmp['Fim real'], 'Sem Falha')
`

`
ValueError: left keys must be sorted
`
I don't understand why

Comment: @VitorFernandes Sort `df1` by `Data`, `df2` by `DSTART`: `df1 = df1.sort_values('Data')`. (Your sample dataframes are already sorted). You need to be careful with indexing.

Comment: The two dataframe merge. This work ir for to merge a data frame of industrial data and maintenance data, I export the df to excel, but I found a problem. 26/10/2020 07:00 until 26/10/2021 we had a maintenance. The dataframe of the result show to me that this maintenance occurs beetween 27/10/2021 and 28/10/2021. I found more examples like this. In the code I put:  
#
_dadosMan['Inicio Real'] = pd.to_datetime(_dadosMan['Inicio Real'])
_dadosMan['Fim real'] = pd.to_datetime(_dadosMan['Fim real'])
_dadosPIMS['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(_dadosPIMS['Data'])

Comment: Then I use like you say:
##
##
_dadosPIMS = _dadosPIMS.sort_values('Data')
_dadosMan = _dadosMan.sort_values('Inicio Real')
##
##
tmp = pd.merge_asof(_dadosPIMS,_dadosMan, left_on='Data', right_on='Inicio Real')
_dadosPIMS['Falha'] = tmp['Falha'].where((tmp['Data'] > tmp['Inicio Real']) & (tmp['Data'] <= tmp['Fim real']), 'Sem Falha')
_dadosPIMS['Ordem'] = tmp['Ordem'].where((tmp['Data'] > tmp['Inicio Real']) & (tmp['Data'] <= tmp['Fim real']), 'Sem Falha')